# combining two views/queries

Tags: mysql

So I have two queries I created as Views:
The Output of each query is:

Date, Count(*)

I would like to combine the two queries so output is:

Date, Count(*), Count(*)

Where the first Count(*) is from the first query and the Second Count(*) is from the second Query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the limited information you have provided, try this:
(it might need to be a FULL OUTER JOIN if rows can exist on one view and not the other view for a given date.

```
SELECT a.DATE AS "DATE"
    ,a.Count AS CountOfA
    ,b.Count AS CountOfB
FROM Query1 a
JOIN Query2 b ON b.DATE = a.DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
COALESCE([v1].[Date],[v2].[Date]) AS [Date]
,ISNULL([v1].COUNT([col]),0) AS [Count1]
,ISNULL([v2].COUNT([col],0) AS [Count2]
FROM [Database].[schema].[view1] AS [v1]

FULL OUTER JOIN [Database].[schema].[view2] AS [v2]
    ON [v1].[Date] = [v2].[Date]
```

The reason I'm using FULL OUTER JOIN and COALESCE is because one view may have a date that the other one does not (for example, view one having 9/9, 9/11 and view2 having 9/9, 9/10, 9/11).  With FULL OUTER JOIN, you're ensuring all dates in both views are represented.

I wouldn't suggest using * in your COUNT function from views, just pick a column you know is unique and use that.

Comment: This is invalid standard SQL. How do you know enderwigg uses a DBMS that supports this?